# How to replace the comma in windows batch loop?

Tags: string, windows, loops, batch-file, replace

I'm writing a windows batch script to supervise jvm memusage. In my laptop, memusage is comma delimeterd. I'd like to replace the comma with an empty character so it can be easily handlered as an integer.

But when I write the codes below, the value of memSize is always empty. How may I get the value? Thanks.

```
rem @echo off
:RESCAN
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem find every java process
tasklist /nh /fo table |find /i "java.exe" > temp.txt
for /F "tokens=1,2,5" %%I in (temp.txt) do (
set memSize=%%K
set memSize=%%memSize:,=%
echo %%memSize%
)
endlocal
del /f temp.txt
ping -n 10 0.0.0.0  > nul
goto :RESCAN
```

Comment: Where have you got this strange double-percent syntax from (`%%memSize%`)?? It's just wrong (unless you've got a `for` variable reference like `%%K`)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have delayed expansion enabled you are not using it.  So you need to make two changes to your code.  Notice the usage of the exclamation point to use the variables.  Your syntax is also wrong when using the percent symbols.  You would normally just use a single percent symbol on each side of the environmental variable name.

```
set memSize=!memSize:,=!
echo !memSize!
```

Comment: Indeed. I did two things to make it work. 1. I removed endlocal 2. I changed set statements as you decribed. Thank you.

Comment: But then I have two questions. 1. what is the difference between ! and % there? Since when I use % to replace !, the code break again. 2. when I use endlocal after the loop, I'm hoping that enabling delayed expansion to the loop is good enough since I do not need to refer to any variable after the loop. What did I miss about the concept? Thank you again.

Comment: @Xun, when the code is inside a parenthesized code block and changing the contents of a variable or creating new variables, you need to use delayed expansion to reference those variables.  This means you must use exclamation points.  You can use percent symbols when not inside a parenthesized code block.